# Proving Existence of Field Extension

Tags: field-theory

This seems so simple that it doesn't warrant a proof, but how would one prove this if asked to? If $K$ is a field and $f(x)\in K[x]$ is monic, then prove that there exists some field $L\supseteq K$ and some $\xi\in L$ such that $f(\xi)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is irreducible, then we can prove that $\frac{K[x]}{(f(x))}$ is a field extension of $K$ and $(f(x))+x$ is a root of $f(x)$, here $f(x)$ is a polynomial over $K$ with identifying $K$ inside $\frac{K[x]}{(f(x))}$.

If $f$ is reducible, apply the above steps for one of its irreducible factor $g(x)$ and get a root for the factor $g(x)$ in $\frac{K[x]}{(g(x))}$ , which will also a root for $f$. here $f(x)$ is a polynomial over $K$ with identifying $K$ inside $\frac{K[x]}{(g(x))}$.

Comment: @tyler0816 write it as product of irreducible polynomials and do the same step by step for each factor.

Comment: $K[x]/(f)$ is not a field unless $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: ya. I have change it.

Comment: @tc1729 the notation $(f(x))$ means ideal generated by $(f(x))$ in the ring $K[x]$ and $(f(x)) + x$ denote the coset of this ideal.

Comment: If @GA316 had used the notation $\overline x$ for the image of $x$ in $K[x]/(f(x))$, it might have been a little clearer. Then he’s just saying that $f(\overline x)=0$ in the new field.